# vtkplotter - How to set a colormap

Tags: python, 3d, vtk, imaging, medical-imaging

I'm working with labeled DICOMs, and I'm using vtkplotter to visualize the 3D model. Each voxel has a label that identifies the recognized part of bone, ranging from -1024 to a value that varies according to the DICOM scan. How can I assign a specific color to each scalar value? I tried with color(), but from what I understand I can only insert in an orderly way the colors corresponding to the value starting from the minimum. I have to specify for a certain scalar value x the color y.

Code snippet that I use to show the 3D model:

```py
from vtkplotter import *

volume = load('Letter:/dicom_folder')
volume.color(['white', 'red', 'yellow'])
volume.alpha([0.0, 0.5, 0.5])

volume.show()
```

**EDIT**:

I solved it like this:

```py
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonDataModel import vtkPiecewiseFunction
from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import vtkColorTransferFunction, vtkVolumeProperty
from vtkplotter import *

volume = load('Letter:/dicom_folder')

volumeColor = vtkColorTransferFunction()
r, g, b = getColor('white')
volumeColor.AddRGBPoint(-1024, r, g, b)
r, g, b = getColor('yellow')
volumeColor.AddRGBPoint(-1023, r, g, b)
r, g, b = getColor('blue')
volumeColor.AddRGBPoint(-1022, r, g, b)


volumeScalarOpacity = vtkPiecewiseFunction()
volumeScalarOpacity.AddPoint(-1024, 0.0)
volumeScalarOpacity.AddPoint(-1023, 0.5)
volumeScalarOpacity.AddPoint(-1022, 0.5)


volumeProperty = vtkVolumeProperty()
volumeProperty.SetColor(volumeColor)
volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(volumeScalarOpacity)
volumeProperty.SetInterpolationTypeToLinear()
volumeProperty.ShadeOn()
volumeProperty.SetAmbient(0.4)
volumeProperty.SetDiffuse(0.6)
volumeProperty.SetSpecular(0.2)

volume.SetProperty(volumeProperty)

volume.show()
```

If you have better or more efficient solutions please let me know.

Comment: If you found a solution, post it as an *answer*, do not edit the question.

Comment: @musicamante Done, thanks for reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonDataModel import vtkPiecewiseFunction
from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import vtkColorTransferFunction, vtkVolumeProperty
from vtkplotter import *

volume = load('Letter:/dicom_folder')

volumeColor = vtkColorTransferFunction()
r, g, b = getColor('white')
volumeColor.AddRGBPoint(-1024, r, g, b)
r, g, b = getColor('yellow')
volumeColor.AddRGBPoint(-1023, r, g, b)
r, g, b = getColor('blue')
volumeColor.AddRGBPoint(-1022, r, g, b)


volumeScalarOpacity = vtkPiecewiseFunction()
volumeScalarOpacity.AddPoint(-1024, 0.0)
volumeScalarOpacity.AddPoint(-1023, 0.5)
volumeScalarOpacity.AddPoint(-1022, 0.5)


volumeProperty = vtkVolumeProperty()
volumeProperty.SetColor(volumeColor)
volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(volumeScalarOpacity)
volumeProperty.SetInterpolationTypeToLinear()
volumeProperty.ShadeOn()
volumeProperty.SetAmbient(0.4)
volumeProperty.SetDiffuse(0.6)
volumeProperty.SetSpecular(0.2)

volume.SetProperty(volumeProperty)

volume.show()
```